# can't create Android project

Tags: android

I'am beginner in Android I can't create android project, can you help me ? I already installed jdk I don't know what's missing
[first page android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiriE.png)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project.html

Comment: Did you give your project "Untitled" as its name? I think your project didn't load properly. Try closing and opening the project again.

Answer (score 1):

windows installation:

1. Install JDK first before A.S.
2. Install Android Studio with SDK
3. Check whether Android PATH already in your environment path
4. Then follow this https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to simply follow the android developer official page to start your first project.[google official blog](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

And once you download the Android studio ,then follow the following link.[to start developing your first project.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html)

Answer (score 0):

If gradle build finishes without error (see event log at the bottom-end of your android studio) and if you has added any activity (during project setup or later) change the view to android from project and you can find layout folder under res and also activity.java in java/{your package.name}.
Hope this helps.